# Procedure to find a specific EXPRESSION in all tables in a specific schema in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Hope you're doing well.
Since I'm new to Oracle database and PL/SQL it's a bit difficult for me to understand complicated queries and now I'm trying to figure out what this procedure exactly does.I think it tries to find a specific expression but I do not understand the way  it tries to do that
This is the procedure body:

```
    create or replace procedure find_expr is     
      a number;
      begin
        for rec in (select 'select count(*) from ' || table_name || ' where ' ||
                            column_name || ' like ''%05510%''' col_name
                    from user_tab_columns t) loop
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec.col_name
      into a;

    if a > 0 then
      insert into find_expr_log values (sysdate, substr(rec.col_name, 22, 50)); 
      commit;
    end if;

  end loop;
exception
  when others then
    null;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a different approach to the same.

Adding the answer on top of the correct answer, **just to reduce the manual work**.

The following query will directly identify the number of rows in each table which is matching the criteria.

```
select table_name, column_name,
  to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select count(1) as c '
      || 'from ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || column_name || ' like ''%05510%'''))
  returning content)) as c
from user_tab_columns
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR2','NUMBER')  -- ALL DATATYPES YOU WANT TO SEARCH
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to try to run:

```
select 'select count(*) from ' || table_name || ' where ' || column_name || ' like ''%05510%''' col_name
from user_tab_columns t
```

Does it produce a list of queries?

What is the purpose of each query? >> Each query will serve for one column within one table. And it returns COUNT value where column data like '%05510%'

`For rec in loop` statement will loop rows produced by the result above, it checks if count > 0 (means there is a record data like '%05510%') then insert a record to `find_expr_log` table.

Hope this helps.